# xcode - how to fill a view within the bounds of main application

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

Im using Storyboard and I have a tableview that fits the entire viewcontroller.

When I run the app I get something like this in the footer of the app.

[image]

If you see the storyboard designer, the tableview fits the view.

[image]

So if you see there is like a gap between the bottom of the view so the tableview is not filling that gap.

Any clue?

Comment: That's the status bar height at bottom.

Comment: How can I get rid of that?